# C and C++ difference behavior

Tags: c++, c

I have created two template project in Eclipse with CDT plugin(one is C project, another C++), and have compiled two very similar projects(as for me) but I get absolutely different console outputs. Why this outputs so different?
  C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int numbers[5];
      int * p;
      p = numbers;  *p = 10;
      p++;  *p = 20;
      p = &numbers[2];  *p = 30;
      p = numbers + 3;  *p = 40;
      p = numbers;  *(p+4) = 50;
      int n;
      for (n=0; n<5; n++)
        printf("%c ",numbers[n]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output
 some garbage

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numbers[5];
      int * p;
      p = numbers;  *p = 10;
      p++;  *p = 20;
      p = &numbers[2];  *p = 30;
      p = numbers + 3;  *p = 40;
      p = numbers;  *(p+4) = 50;
      for (int n=0; n<5; n++)
        cout << numbers[n] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

output

10, 20, 30, 40, 50

Comment: Have you tried the `%d` format option in `printf`? `%c` is for single characters.

Comment: Why are you setting `p` equal to `numbers`? More importantly, why not just numbers[0], numbers[1], etc?

Comment: A beautiful example of what's wrong with `printf` (in addition to its lack of safety and its lack of extensibility).

Comment: By the way, if you are confused as to why some people are suggesting `%d` and some `%i`, they do the exact same thing in this case. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders): "d, i : int as a signed decimal number. `'%d'` and `'%i'` are synonymous for output, but are different when used with `scanf()` for input (using `%i` will interpret a number as hexadecimal if it's preceded by `0x`, and octal if it's preceded by `0`.)"

Answer (score 23):

You are printing `int` as `char` in C.

Change

```
printf("%c ",numbers[n]);
```

to

```
printf("%d ",numbers[n]);
```

Answer (score 8):

You print the ASCII value of the integers. Try

```
printf("%i", numbers[n])
```

instead of

```
printf("%c", numbers[n])
```

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to output the numbers as characters, causing your odd output.
The code worked fine for me as this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int numbers[5];
  int * p;
  p = numbers;  *p = 10;
  p++;  *p = 20;
  p = &numbers[2];  *p = 30;
  p = numbers + 3;  *p = 40;
  p = numbers;  *(p+4) = 50;
  int n;
  for (n=0; n<5; n++)
    printf("%d ",numbers[n]);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note the %d, rather than %c

Answer (score 1):

You need %d to print integer and %c to print char in C

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Look at your below statement

```
printf("%c ",numbers[n]);
```

You are using %c to print int, which is wrong.

To be specific printf has been borrowed from C and has some limitations. The most common mentioned limitation of printf is type safety, as it relies on the programmer to correctly match the format string with the arguments. The second limitation that comes again from the varargs environment is that you cannot extend the behavior with user defined types. The printf knows how to print a set of types, and that's all that you will get out of it. Still, it for the few things that it can be used for, it is faster and simpler to format strings with printf than with c++ streams.